# AWS dropwizard app unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: amazon-ec2, certificate, ssl-certificate, dropwizard, sslhandshakeexception

I have a dropwizard app running on AWS EC2. Recently i started getting this error when trying to reach MailGun or Twilio APIs

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
find valid certification path to requested target

! at 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild( 
SunCertPathBuilder.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268) 
~[na:1.7.0_91]

! at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(
PKIXValidator.java:380)     ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! ... 79 common frames omitted

! Causing: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building 
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target

! at 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) ~ . 
[na:1.7.0_91]

! at 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(
PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
! at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~ . 
[na:1.7.0_91]

! at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(
X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326) ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! at 
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(
X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(
X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! at 
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(
ClientHandshaker.java:1454) ~[na:1.7.0_91]

! ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Not sure how to move forward. Should i install Twilio & MailGun's certs on my server? Or is there a config i need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the PKIX path building error (unable to find valid certification path to requested target) means than somehow SSL is not working, probably because the Certificate Auth in java 1.7 are too old and no more valid.

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks @maborg. i upgraded to Java 1.8 on the Linux server and so far so good.